# Transform an array to another array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to transform this array to another array using lodash 2.4.2:

authorities will be mapped in roles. and we don't touch the other properties.

From:

```
      {

      "items": [
        {
          "_id": "admin",
          "authorities": [
            {
              "name": "ROLE_ADMIN"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "user",
          "authorities": [
            {
              "name": "ROLE_USER"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

to this array

```
    {

    "items": [
        {
          "_id": "admin",
          "roles": [

              "ROLE_ADMIN"

          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "user",
          "role": [

              "ROLE_USER"

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

can you help me please?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Show what you have tried. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) said, in the future posts you must provide examples of code, that you've written to solve your problem.

Here's the solution, it's pretty simple:

```
const initialObject = {
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": "admin",
      "authorities": [
        {
          "name": "ROLE_ADMIN"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "_id": "user",
      "authorities": [
        {
          "name": "ROLE_USER"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const processedObject = _
  .map(initialObject.items, item => {
    return {
      _id: item._id,
      roles: _.map(item.authorities, a => a.name)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a re-mapping of the key name. For performance reasons I would try to avoid the use of `delete`. You can see the performance differences in this [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/16), only use 'delete' if the object gets persisted later on.

```
for (var item of items) {
  item.roles =  item.authorities
  // possible but slow
  // delete item.authorities
  item.authorities = undefined
}
```

Edit: @vanelizarov code is even better if you want to avoid mutation of the object itself and clean properties. but it is also slower.

```
vanelizarov code:   x 5,025,370 ops/sec ±1.30% (90 runs sampled)
my code:            x 31,583,811 ops/sec ±0.95% (92 runs sampled)
```